# dynamic multiple column layout

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to use CSS or JavaScript to create multiple columns that allow images to overlap columns and then wordwrap around them without sacrificing the integrity of the columns. I found masonry.js can do some of this but not all that I require.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help you http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/htmlcss-tutorials/an-introduction-to-the-css3-multiple-column-layout-module/. I never used it but I think that the browser should correctly handle columns-* properties in CSS3 and surely handle every overlap cases.